# blender 4.1 how use `bpy.ops.object.geometry_node_bake_single`

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

In Blender 4.1's Geometry Nodes, the Bake node has been updated. The bake button within it has a Python code:

`bpy.ops.object.geometry_node_bake_single(session_uid=233, modifier_name="_Hair_Test", bake_id=1501904070)`
[image]
The question is how to obtain the values of `session_uid` and `bake_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I found it! XD!

```
bpy.context.active_object.modifiers['_Hair_Test'].bakes[3].id_data.session_uid
bpy.context.active_object.modifiers['_Hair_Test'].bakes[3].node
bpy.context.active_object.modifiers['_Hair_Test'].bakes[3].bake_id
```